# PHP Project configuration directory - Best Practices?

Tags: php, linux, configuration

I use a Linux PC for development purposes. In the PC I develop a few PHP based web sites and projects. Each project belongs to a different client and the majority of those is hosted in different hosting companies.

The directory structure of each project is:

```
bin
lib
www
logs
conf
```

For each project I use some standard, developed by me, libraries that require a standard configuration, which is stored in the "conf" directory, like for example, the DB connection data.

For that I use the variable

```
$configdir=$_SERVER['HOME'].DIRECORY_SEPARATOR."conf
```

For instance, the backup script use the file $HOME/conf/db.ini in order to retrieve the specific data and backup the DB of the project.

On the production servers, the variable $configdir is (obviously) different for each project. But, on the development server is NOT.

I do not want to use pathinfo, or basename or dirname since I want to use the configuration file path in scripts that run from any possible depth. For example, I would like to use that variable in a script under $HOME/bin/calculations/script.php.

Since, on the development server, $configdir will show the same directory for **all** projects, I need your ideas on how to keep the **same** structure, and use the same code in production **and** development while that variable use the correct "$HOME" for each project.

Comment: Your question is too broad (no certain problem). Use directory structure that way for you to be comfortable with that in future. For samples - just open any existing framework's code.

Comment: The directory structure is fine. What is not fine is the way to retrieve the configuration options. I don't see how a framework will help me to solve that problem. Can you provide me an sample?